# Python re: How to match space or no integer in string?

Tags: python

I have files that have a line like this in them.

```
<play locationId="83" touchscreen="false" primary="">
```

Some of them have an integer in them and some of them don't.  I can search properly for an integer.

How do I search for a missing integer?
Some configs may look like:

```
<play locationId="" touchscreen="false" primary="">
```

or

```
<play locationId=" " touchscreen="false" primary="">
```

I want to take the blank spot and put an integer in it.

This is not working:

```
sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(locationID=)"', r'\1"' + mynewnumber, line))
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my full code.  I'm working on the 'else' statement, but I think the 'if' is not letting me search for a space and replace properly.

```
def changeid():

    source = "myfile.config"
    newtext = str(results[1])
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            pattern = r'(?<=locationId=").([^"]+)'  # find 1 or more digits that come
                                              # after the string locationid     
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, newtext, line)) # adds number after locationid
                fileinput.close()
            else:
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(locationID=)"', r'\1"' + newtext, line)) # use sys.stdout.write instead of "print"
                # using re module to format                                                              
                # adds a location id number after locationid even if there was no number originally there        
                fileinput.close()

changeid()
```

Comment: in your example, do you want to replace `83` with `mynewnumber` or leave it as is?

Comment: I want it to be replaced by 'mynewnumber'.  I'm reading that a "<space>?" might work?  <space> represents a real space.

Comment: _"This is not working"_ How so? Does it throw an error? Does it produce wrong output?

Comment: In my cobble-up, the given code simply fails to change the given line.

Comment: Why dont you search for `locationId=" "` and `replace()` it with `locationId="mynewnumber"` ?

Comment: When I run my code, it outputs....      <play locationId="22"false" primary="">

Comment: So it wipes out everything up until the next quotation mark.

Comment: @Prox I'm not sure how you're getting that output. Prune is right about what the output should be.

Comment: Oh, my original pattern for replacing the number if there "IS" a number is probably causing that.  I'll post the entire code up above.    r'(?<=locationId=").([^"]+)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<space>?` will match a space

`\d+` will match a sequence of digits

So let's combine them: 
`locationId="(\d+| ?)`

Alternatively, we could find anything that isn't a quotation mark: 
`locationId="[^"]+`

Put this together:

```
line = '<play locationId="83" touchscreen="false" primary="">'
sys.stdout.write(re.sub('locationId="[^"]+', 'locationId="{}'.format(mynumber), line))
```

Comment: So how do I tie that to a variable called pattern?  pattern = 'locationId="(\d+| ?)'

Comment: sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, newtext, line))